# Possible short in a RAMPS 1.6 board

Tags: electronics, troubleshooting, power-supply, ramps-1.6

I have an FDM 3d printer that used to run on RAMPS 1.4. After accidentally destroyed that board, I bought a [1.6 board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M6Z6DWC) to replace it. I have it connected to a [12 V 30 A power supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LATMSGS), but when I turn on the power, the power indicator LED on the supply briefly lights up and then dies. A multimeter reading between the power terminals gives 0 V. When I disconnect the RAMPS board from the supply, the supply runs fine.

This suggests to me that there is a short somewhere, but I am not confident in that conclusion. How do I check the integrity of my board? Is there a way that I can unit test any of the components?

---

*Notes*: The internet has [some people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p649C7m61qA) talking about quality issues with the 1.6, like bridging and cold solder joints, which I have checked for; I cannot see anything wrong.

I currently have all of the steppers, limit switches, and thermistors connected. I have the stepper drivers installed, each with all 3 micro-stepping jumpers installed.

Comment: can you attach a high res photo of both sides of the board?

Comment: If there is a short the component involved will get very hot very quickly: all the energy is being dissipated through heat. Carefully touching the components with a temperature probe/termistor will give you an idea of the failing component. Also a thermal camera or a IR thermometer can provide some clue.

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco Since I first noticed the behavior, I have not left it on for more than half a second. If my board isn't already fried, I am hoping that this would provide some protection.

Comment: I’m not suggesting to leave it on for long periods: a short of a second might be well enough to raise the temperature of a component above 40/50 C, which is something you should be able to feel with your finger. Obviously if you have better ways to find out where lies the issue than go for it, but without proper tools and no other clues I can’t imagine how to do this.